# vstest.console.exe does not pick up npm packages (jest and jest-editor-support)

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, jestjs, vstest

I can run `jest` tests fine via a `.njsproj` but with a `.csproj` project and a `node_modules` located at `\ClientApp` `vstest.console.exe` does not find the packages needed.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64064559/3850405

> Failed to find "jest" package. "jest" must be installed in the project
> locally. Install "jest" locally using the npm manager via solution
> explorer or with ".npm install jest --save-dev" via the Node.js
> interactive window. Failed to find "jest-editor-support" package.
> "jest-editor-support" must be installed in the project locally.
> Install "jest-editor-support" locally using the npm manager via
> solution explorer or with ".npm install jest-editor-support
> --save-dev" via the Node.js interactive window.

Command:

```
vstest.console.exe "C:\Users\Oscar\source\repos\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\WebApplication1.csproj" "/TestAdapterPath:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\NodeJsTools\TestAdapter"
```

Is there some way to specify the location of either `package.json` or the `node_modules` folder? The project is using `.NET Core 3.1`.

I have followed this guide:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/unit-testing-javascript-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2019

Added the following values to `PropertyGroup` in `.csproj`:

```
<JavaScriptTestFramework>Jest</JavaScriptTestFramework>
<JavaScriptTestRoot>ClientApp\src\tests\</JavaScriptTestRoot>
<GenerateProgramFile>false</GenerateProgramFile>
<SpaRoot>ClientApp\</SpaRoot>
<DefaultItemExcludes>$(DefaultItemExcludes);$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**</DefaultItemExcludes>
```

Tested both with and without `SpaRoot` and `DefaultItemExcludes`.

I have not specified `outdir` or `outfile` option in `tsconfig.json` and I have installed the NuGet [Microsoft.JavaScript.UnitTest](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.JavaScript.UnitTest/).

Working test from `.njsproj` after `jest` and `jest-editor-support` was installed.

[image]